# Fast sliding window mean and std deviation on 2D array with NaN values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I have a large 2D array of size ~30000 x 30000 with NaN values in it. I want to calculate sliding window mean and standard deviation. So far I have been using scipy's uniform_filter to calculate mean and std. dev but as soon as the NaN values are encountered, the calculations fail and output NaN.

After looking at various solutions online, I am still not clear on how to approach this issue and also make it faster.

Any insights into the solution would be helpful.

**1. Sample random 2D array generated with nan values added**

[image: Sample random 2D array generated with nan values added]

**2. df.rolling with min_periods=2 or greater shows top row nan**

[image: df.rolling with min_periods=2 or greater shows to row nan]

**3. df.rolling with min_periods=1 top row not nan but the original nan position gets reduced**

[image: df.rolling with min_periods=1 top row not nan but the original nan position gets reduced]

All in all what I am trying to make sure is that when calculating mean and std. deviation, the NaN's are not used in the calculation

Comment: Use `pandas.DataFrame` and then use [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: Hi @Trenton_M, on converting 2D array to dataframe and applying rolling, the NaN values appear in the first row and also in the location where they were inserted in the output csv file

Comment: Without seeing a minimum sample set and expected output, I don't have more to offer.  Try setting `min_periods : int, default None
Minimum number of observations in window required to have a value (otherwise result is NA). For a window that is specified by an offset, min_periods will default to 1. Otherwise, min_periods will default to the size of the window.`

Comment: [datafeame.mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) skips na by default

Comment: thanks@Trenton_M, my doubt is cleared. Setting the min_periods=1 will check if even single valid value is present in the window, it will be used to rolling window mean calculation while nan's will be skipped

Comment: An additional query is that when implementing the df.rolling(5, min_period=1).std the top row the of the std.deviation shows nan values, why is that?

Comment: What do you expect the mean of a section with a `nan` to output?  What do you want the mean of `[5,6,7,8,nan]` to be?

Comment: You can use `skimage.util.view_as_windows(arr, (5, 1))` (or 1, 5, not sure which axis you're trying to roll over), then `np.nanmean(..., axis=(3, 4))`.

Comment: Hi@Scott, when a nan is within the sliding window, the mean should exclude it from the calculation and use only the valid values that fall within the sliding window. The mean of [5,6,7,8,nan] with a window size of say 3 should be [6,7,7.5,8,nan]

Comment: Hi@Juan, I tried your method, however one of the issues with the skimage view_as_windows function is memory issue when using 2D or higher dimension arrays. Is there a more memory efficient way of processing large 2D arrays with sliding window mean?

Comment: Thanks @Trenton_M, the pandas.rolling has resolved my issue.